# I can't display php on my webpage I always got PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException : could not find driver

Tags: php

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION :**

No matter what code I put in login.php I always got this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in 
C:\MAMP\htdocs\website\login.php:4 
Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\website\login.php(4): PDO->__construct('C:\\Users\\neb\\...') #1 
{main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\website\login.php on line 4
```

I'm using MAMP I have installed php. When I check in the EV(Environment variables) it's in Path :\MAMP\htdocs\website\php8.2.4

So my php is actually php8.2.4
BUT the php of MAMP is 7.4.1 I don't know If it has something to do with the error.

**CODE :**

```
<?php
$fullname = "Adam";
echo "Hi $fullname and welcome on the website!";

?>
```

I also tried with :

```
<?php

phpinfo(); 

?>
```

But as I said earlier no matter what I put in login.php I got the same error

**WHAT I'VE TRIED :**

1. check if php was installed with php --version in cmd
2. install php
3. change the directory of php

I still don't know how to solve this please help

**EDIT**

[image: phpversion]

I did replace php8.2 by php7.4.1 and Also restart MAMP But the error persist

**EDIT 2 :**

[image: theimage]

Comment: This is not the whole code you have.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: your error message makes no sense in context of code you presented. For me this is not `login.php` error is about

Comment: please show us the section PDO support on phpinfo(), your screenshot is cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly i recommend to create a test page and output the phpinfo there then check if the PDO extension is loaded. If theres no value then it seems that something is going on with your php.ini file.

1. Check file here /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/phpx.y.z/conf/php.ini
   [Source](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/FAQ/Where-can-I-find-the-php.ini-file/)
2. If you cant find the file there, look on another location and copy
   it there
3. Restart MAMP

**UPDATE:**

Look in your php.ini' file and uncomment this line:

> extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: It still display the error even if I changed the php version

Comment: first thing to check is create a dummy PHP page with phpinfo, what is printing out ?

Comment: Okay I got the whole thing of PHP Version 7.4.1 But when I tried with login.php it didn't work So I created another page like you said "test.php" and it dispalyed the whole thing of PHP Version 7.4.1

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the PDO section on phpinfo? what do you mean by the whole thing :)

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I put the screenshot

Comment: check the updated answer, is this line commented ? if so uncomment it.

Comment: This Line is actually not commented